# In Victoria Australia can you travel more than 5km to inspect a property under stage 4 restrictions?

Tags: australia

Under the stage 4 restrictions as of 01 - October - 2020 can you travel more than the 5km boundary to inspect a property either to potentially buy or rent?

This question applies to Victoria Australia in the Melbourne area and not regional Victoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is now moot, but the answer at that time was: Yes you can do so.
https://web.archive.org/web/20201005013734/https://www.dhhs.vic.gov.au/homes-and-property-metropolitan-melbourne-second-step-covid-19

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if some of the information backing up the answer were included in the answer, rather than behind a link.